# Getting results of a method to display in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have no idea how to start doing this.

I have a grid which I have already populate some data and presented in a table format. I am able to click on each individual cell and it will indicate which cell and its values.

However I need these values and the cell I click on to be shown in another section of the grid. How do I go about doing this? Not sure on how to do the binding though since my click will trigger an event and I am not sure how I can actually push the data from the event code to the grid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean 'Selected' to select individual cell? or row? Not like MS Excel, WPF DataGrid basically does not support selecting each individual cell, but rows. The following my answer is about selecting rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use binding SelectedItems of DataGrid to solve your problem. Just check the following code.

**[Updated]** At first glance, as SelectedItems type is IList, it seems not to implement  INotifyCollectionChanged, but the actual object type of SelectedItems is `internal class SelectedItemCollection : ObservableCollection<object>`. **[/Updated]**

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="DS1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DS1, Path=SelectedItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            customers.Add(new Customer {FirstName = "name" + i, LastName = "last" + i});
        }
        DataContext = customers;
    }
}

//Defines the customer object
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: nice that is a short solution. I actually saw this example before but never thought of it. thanks!